# Foreign key returning empty result set

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, web-development-server

I've created a foreign key to link two tables:

1. The addresses of my users (foreign key)
2. User login details (primary key).

However, when I create the foreign key no details that the user enters are saved in the address table. Whereas when the address table doesn't have a foreign key, it inserts the input into the address table just fine.

I don't have much experience with MySQL so the error could be something trivial, however I cannot find the solution myself. I am using PHP procedural.

Here is a sample of my database:

Address Table containing foreign key:

```
1   id Primary          int(11)         No  None        AUTO_INCREMENT      
2   address_fk Index    int(11)         No  None            
3   address_line_one    varchar(25) utf8_general_ci     No  None                
4   address_line_two    varchar(25) utf8_general_ci     No  None
```

User details with primary key:

```
1   id Primary      int(11)         No             None     AUTO_INCREMENT      
2   user_email      varchar(320)    utf8_general_ci     No  None            
3   user_password   char(60)        utf8_general_ci     No  None
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post sample of data and structures of your tables

Comment: I've added in the relevant tables, I haven't currently got any data in these tables apart from one set of details for the user login.

Comment: Only table's CREATE TABLE scripts provides the information needed - replace the table-form structures please. And add some sample data (as INSERT INTO scripts) and desired result for this data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A foreign key in a child table has to reference an existing primary key column in the parent table. If your primary key is the *ID* column in your *User Details* table, your foreign key will be an *ID* column in the *Addresses* table, as it will point to the *ID* column in your parent table.

Your current setup indicates an *address_fk* column as the foreign key; however, there is no such column in the *User Details* table to which it can point.